# Solving recurrence relation $a_n=a_{n-1} + 3(n-1), a_0=1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

a) $a_n = a_{n-1} + 3(n - 1)$

My work:

Homog. Soln:

$a_n - a_{n-1} = 0$

$\lambda - 1 = 0\Rightarrow \lambda=1$

$a_n = c_1 1^n$

$a_0 = c_1 = 1$

So the homogeneous solution is $a_n = 1$.

Particular soln:

Guess solution is $Bn + C$.

$(Bn + C) - (B(n-1) + C) = 3n - 3$

$(Bn - Bn) + (C + B - C) = 3n - 3$

So: $(Bn - Bn) = 3n$ and $(C + B - C) = -3$

But that seems nonsensical, and not sure where to go from there.

Comment: When a recurrence relation is of the type$ a_n + \alpha a_{n-1}... = f(n) \times {\lambda}^n $ where $f(n)$ is a polynomial then the answear you should be guessing is $n^s q(n) {\lambda}^n$ where s is the multiplicity of the root lambda in the relation's characteristic polynomial and q(n) is a polynomial of the same degree of f(n). Notice that your relation is equal to $f(n) \times 1^n$ so you need to add $n^1$ to your guessed solution because 1 is a root of the characteristic polynomial

Answer (score 3):

$$a_n-a_{n-1}=3(n-1)$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k-a_{k-1})=\sum_{k=1}^n3(k-1)=3(\sum_1^nk-\sum_1^n1)=3n(n+1)/2-3n$$

$$a_n-a_0=3n(n+1)/2-3n$$

$$a_n=1+3n(n+1)/2-3n$$

Comment: K starts counting at 1 since $a_{-1}$ is undefined

Comment: Notice that because of this your solution yields $a_1 = -2$ when it should be $a_1 = 1$

Comment: @Francisco, it's actually $a_0=1$. I've made a correction, please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $F(n)=3(n-1)=(3n-3)=(3n-3)(1)^n$. We need to keep in mind the following theorem.

> **Theorem:** Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ satisfies the linear non-homogenous recurrence relation $$a_n=c_1a_{n-1}+c_2a_{n-2}+… c_ka_{n-k} +F(n)$$ where $c_1,c_2,…c_k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $F(n)= (b_tn^t+b_{t-1}n^{t-1}+…b_1n+b_0)s^n$, where $b_0, b_1, …b_t, s \in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> When $s$ is not a root of the characteristic equation of the associated linear homogenous recurrence relation, there is a particular solution of the form $$(p_tn^t + p_{t-1}n^{t-1}+…p_1n+p_0)s^n$$
>
> When $s$ is a root with multiplicity $m$, then the solution is of the form $$n^m(p_tn^t + p_{t-1}n^{t-1}+…p_1n+p_0)s^n$$

Taken from *Rosen, Discrete Mathematics & Its Applications.*

Coming back to the question, there is thus a particular solution of the form $n(p_1n+p_0)=p_1n^2+p_0n$ as $s=1$ is a root of degree $1$ of the characteristic equation.

Hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you can do the descent $$\begin{array}{ccc}a_n &= &a_{n-1}+3(n-1)\\&=&a_{n-2}+3(n-2)+3(n-1)\\&=&\cdots\\&=&a_1+3\cdot[1+2+3+\cdots+(n-1)]\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

Let $a_n=b_n+p_0+p_1n+p_2n^2+p_3n^3+\cdots$

$$3n-3=a_n-a_{n_1}=b_n-b_{n-1}+p_1+p_2(2n-1)+p_3\{n^3-(n-1)^3\}+\cdots$$

Set $p_r=0\forall r\ge3$

and $2p_1=3,p_1-p_2=-3$ to find $b_n=b_{n-1}$

$$=\cdots=b_0=a_0=?$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep it simple. The first thing to try is $a_n=f_n+pn+q$. That doesn't work, so take it to $a_n=f_n+pn^2+qn$. You'll readily find that $p=-q=3/2$ and finally, for $a_0=1$ we get

$$a_n=1+\frac{3}{2}n(n-1)$$

Answer (score 0):

Your recurrence is particularly simple and the easiest approach seems to be the one suggested by Gerry Myerson. But the standard approach of generating functions works with almost equal ease.

Let $f(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$ so that $$f(x) - xf(x) = a_{0}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n}-a_{n-1})x^{n}=1+3x^{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}=1+\frac{3x^{2}}{(1-x)^{2}}$$ so that $$f(x) =\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{3x^2}{(1-x)^{3}}$$ Now via binomial theorem we can easily see that $$a_{n} =1+3\cdot\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$